# Convert Lat/Long to UTM

Tags: google-maps, latitude-longitude, utm

I want to convert Lat/Long to UTM. When I search on net I am getting completely different formulas.

e.g. Lat/Long, 21.0909,79.067635

How to convert it to UTM?

Comment: Please clarify what is your overall task: is it batch processing of a text-file or something else? Would you like to do it via script using existing libraries or via GUI or all you need is a formula?

Comment: @SS_Rebelious I need to use in my C++ code. We need to convert Lat/Long to UTM to perform map related operations.

Comment: @pranitkothari Have a look to almost same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9340485/conversion-between-latitude-longitude-to-utm-notation

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you are not interested in studying geodesy, so you should just use [proj4 C++ API](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/wiki/ProjAPI) for your project for coordinate transformation tasks.

As to the formulas, you may read [this guide](http://www.iogp.org/pubs/373-07-2.pdf) (one of the [EPSG Guiding notes](http://www.epsg.org/GuidanceNotes)). Coordinate transformation for TM/UTM described there starting from page 45.

Comment: The link to “this guide” is no longer available ☹

Comment: @mirabilos, ty for the information. New link provided - check it out.

Answer (score 2):

The open source GIS Whitebox Geospatial Analysis Systems (http://www.uoguelph.ca/~hydrogeo/Whitebox/) contains a tool called Coordinate System Transformations that can be used to convert either shapefile or raster files to UTM from lat/long or vice versa. You can also look at the specific algorithm that I used for the conversions here: 
http://code.google.com/p/whitebox-geospatial-analysis-tools/source/browse/trunk/ConversionTools/src/plugins/CoordinateSystemTransformation.java

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are most welcome to copy my calculations from here [Test of ORACLE DB functions converting lat-long to utm and mgrs with real data known to be correct?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/71387/test-of-oracle-db-functions-converting-lat-long-to-utm-and-mgrs-with-real-data-k)
As far as i know the utm function works for everywhere while the MGRS works for everywhere except the poles.
That formulas has been random check with www.earthpoint.us/Convert.aspx