# can i convert the lat/longs to meters

Tags: arcgis-server

I have placed coordinates in my map,but i want these in meters.
Please help me how to convert these.

Simple Map
    
    
    
      html,body,#map{
      height:100%;
      width:100%
      }
    
    
    
      var map,overviewMapDijit;

```
  require(["esri/map",
           "esri/dijit/OverviewMap",
           "dojo/parser",
           "esri/geometry/webMercatorUtils",
           "dojo/dom",
           "dijit/layout/BorderContainer",
           "dijit/layout/ContentPane",             
           "dojo/domReady!"], function(Map,OverviewMap,parser,webMercatorUtils,dom) {
    parser.parse();
    map = new Map("map", {
      basemap: "streets",  
      center: [82.45, 22.75],
      zoom: 5
    });
    overviewMapDijit = new OverviewMap({
      map: map,
      visible: true
    });
    overviewMapDijit.startup();

    map.on("load", function() {

      map.on("mouse-move", showCoordinates);
      map.on("mouse-drag", showCoordinates);
    });

    function showCoordinates(evt) {

      var mp = webMercatorUtils.webMercatorToGeographic(evt.mapPoint);

      dom.byId("info").innerHTML = mp.x.toFixed(5) + ", " + mp.y.toFixed(5);
    }
 });
</script>
</head>

<body>  
 <div id="map" style="position:relative; width:100%; height:100%; border:3px solid #000;">
  <span id="info" style="position:absolute; left:15px; bottom:5px; color:#000; z-index:50;"></span> 
 </div>        
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% clear on what you are asking, but I'm guessing that you are asking about the conversion of lat long to UTM? The question has been previously asked here: [Lat Long to UTM Conversion](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/67829/want-to-convert-lat-long-to-utm). You also may want to look here: [Stack overflow Q&A with the math for conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639695/how-to-convert-latitude-or-longitude-to-meters)  If you have another coordinate system in mind, you can reproject within your code [see here for reprojection](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/util_project.html).